# Connect to SQL server using Linq, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I`m creating a website using asp.net, and I need to use a local SQL server (using Microsoft SQL server). And I have created database and tables in it using the MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Now I successfully connect to the database and do some simple add/query using the following commands:

```
string connectionString = "data source=ABCD\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PMD;Trusted_Connection=yes;";

string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO PMD (username, userID, userAddress)";
sqlQuery +=               " VALUES (@user,    id,     add)";
SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, dataConnection);

dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", USER.Value);
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", ID.Value);
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("add", ADDRESS.Text);

dataConnection.Open();
dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
dataConnection.Close();
```

The command above can add one column to the table, with values stated.
The query is done in a similar way. Compared with Linq, this is not very concise.

So I was wondering how can I change the code so I can use Linq.

The biggest question for me now is how to connect to the base. I already know all the syntax of Linq.

```
eg: var query=from c in db.username where c.Contain(“Micheal”) select c (or maybe db.PMD.username)
```

How can I get the db to link with ABCD/SQLEXPRESS, table PMD?

Comment: are you using entity framework or linq to sql?

Comment: @Daniel I don`t know what I`m using right now. I searched "how to connect to sql, asp.net" and find the code and it`s working. Now I would like to change it so I can use linq to sql.

Comment: @DanielA.White OP is using neither. The above code is basic ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need an **Object/Relational Mapper** (O/RM). You can't just put LINQ on top of your old ADO.NET code.

Microsoft provides two: **Linq2SQL** and **Entity Framework**.

**Linq2SQL** has been discontinued. If I had to choose between the two, I'd go with **Entity Framework**.

Here you can find an introduction: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thanks for the reply. So I cannot just add some code to it and use Linq to SQL?

Comment: No, you can't. You need a LINQ provider that translates LINQ queries to SQL. This is where Entity Framework comes in.

Comment: @user1739292, well, setting up an Entity Framework context from a database takes all of 5 minutes, so don't think it will take forever.  It's pretty quick.

Comment: thanks for the above reply. I`m using Webmatrix to develop the website, not VS. so it is the same process?

Comment: Have a look at the first answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626492/linq-to-sql-for-webmatrix-web-pages

Comment: @DennisTraub Thanks, I have a feeling it would be very useful. I don`t have enough points to "up" though, sorry about that, haha.

Comment: @user1739292 You can accept the answer by using the checkmark. And welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

For example, install [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906.aspx), then [connect to sql server with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710654/how-to-connect-to-sqlexpress-for-entity-framework-using-visual-studio-2010-expre)